# What is the relation between the $L^2$ norm on the boundary vs. in the domain?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

In some notes I have, where boundedness of some functional was shown, I found
$$ \|v\|_{L^2(\partial\Omega)} \leq \|v\|_{L^2(\Omega)}.$$
Where does this inequality come from?

Answer (score 2):

This is false. Consider $\Omega:=[0,1]$ and $f(x):=1$ for $x<1/n$, $f(x):=0$ for $x>1/n$. Then the boundary norm is 1, while the interior norm is $1/\sqrt{n}$.

In general, $L^2$ functions cannot even be evaluated on the boundary - the boundary is measure 0, and $L^2$ 'functions' are only equivalence classes up to sets of measure zero. Obviously, continuous functions on $\overline{\Omega}$ can be evaluated on $\partial \Omega$. You can continuously extend this to Sobolev functions on $\Omega$ (continuously in the Sobolev space norm $\|u\|_{W^{1,2}(\Omega)}^2:=\|u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2+\|\nabla u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2$), and the result is called a *trace*. The trace operator is *bounded* as an operator from for sets with sufficiently regular boundary (see e.g. Theorem 1.5.1.2 in Grisvard's book *Elliptic Problems in Nonsmooth Domains*), but you need a region-dependent constant to appear in your inequality, and you need to use the Sobolev space norm on the right-hand side instead of the $L^2$ norm.

Comment: is this inequality can be reversible? like lower bound has whole domain?